# Fetching related objects

Tags: doctrine, symfony

In Symfony 2 book there is an example of how to do that for ONE $product: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/doctrine.html#fetching-related-objects

It is quite simple:

```
public function showAction($id)
{
$product = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')
    ->find($id);

$categoryName = $product->getCategory()->getName();

// ...
}
```

But what if i want to fetch ALL products with category info joined automatically to each project?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
$products = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')->findAll();
```

However, each time you do a getCategory on a product a sql query will be triggered which could result in performance issues.

What you really want to do is to make yourself a ProductManager service and write an explicit query joining product and category.  So only one sql query will be generated.  The Doctrine 2 manual has plenty of examples.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/reference/query-builder.html

Comment: I thought Doctrine allows to do it more user-friendly... Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can either iterate over the products and get the categories from there. Adjusting the fetch mode on the relations might help in reducing the amount of queries performed.

However, you might also just write a custom DQL query to get what you need. It might look like something like this:

```
SELECT p, c
FROM AcmeStoreBundle:Product p
INNER JOIN p.category c
```

Comment: Can it be done WITHOUT writing SQL query (DQL...)? I mean i want to do the same as is in the example, whithout any extra code..
And if it is not possible, can you please provide a complete php code for it? Also i want to apply some filter options like "active=1 AND foo='bar'". How to add them? thx

Comment: If you want to use filters, than you have to write a query. To keep the code clean, you might want to set-up a repository. Check out http://mackstar.com/blog/2010/10/04/using-repositories-doctrine-2 for details.

Comment: findBy() can help with the filtering.  But in reality as soon as you go beyond the mist basic stuff you will probably end up writing your own queries.  Using Doctrine's query builder make this much easier than using raw sql.

Comment: Writing my own queries which will look similar to SQL... not the best idea, if i use ORM then it MUST do all the work for me. I'm a little bit disappointed in Doctrine :)

Comment: It's not really SQL if you notice. It handles the relations by mapping to the properties in your domain model. Also, if you use a repository, all of those queries get centralized in a single class and the rest of your code is pretty much immune to it all.